# Reorder bibtex elements in a .bst file

Tags: bibtex, bst

I'm writing my master's thesis and I came into trouble with bibliography since any bibliography style do not respond to my needs.

I would like this type of elements order:

P. Lopes, M. A. Silva, A. Pons, T. Tominaga, V. Lavigne, C. Saucier, P. Darriet, P. L.
Teissedre e D. Dubourdieu, 2009, Impact of oxygen dissolved at bottling and transmitted
through closures on the composition and sensory properties of a Sauvignon blanc wine
during bottle storage, Journal of agricultural and food chemistry, 57(21):10261–10270, ACS Publications.

So I edited a .bst file and it came up like this:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "" * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " ed altri" * }
                { " e " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { "" * }
        { "" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    {title}
  if$
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
        { "" }
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
          month
        }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
        'year
        { month " " * year * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "Volume " volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        'skip$
        { " of " * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { "number" }
            { "Number" }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          series empty$
            { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
            { " in " * series * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}


FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        {"Edizione " edition "l" change.case$  * }
        { "Edizione " edition "t" change.case$  * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages n.dashify }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { "chapter" }
        { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
        { "In " booktitle emphasize * }
        { "In " format.editors * ", " * booktitle emphasize * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "Technical Report" }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "t" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
          warning$
          ""
        }
        { "In {\em " journal * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " key * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "In "
    }
    { "Volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { series empty$
            { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              "" *
            }
            { "{\em " * series * "\/}" * }
          if$
        }
        { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { booktitle empty$
            { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              ""
            }
            { "In {\em " booktitle * "\/}" * }
          if$
        }
        { "In " key * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.journal output
  new.sentence
  format.bvolume output
  new.block
  format.edition output
  new.block
  format.pages output 
  new.block
  format.editors output
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages.publisher output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  howpublished address new.block.checkb
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      address empty$
        { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
          organization output
          publisher output
          format.date "year" output.check
        }
        { address output.nonnull
          format.date "year" output.check
          new.sentence
          organization output
          publisher output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        'skip$
        { organization output.nonnull
          address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        { address new.block.checka
          address output
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    { organization address new.block.checkb
      organization output
      address output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { organization output }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  address empty$
    { editor empty$
        { publisher new.sentence.checka }
        { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
          organization output
        }
      if$
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      new.sentence
      editor empty$
        'skip$
        { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  format.date output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}

READ

STRINGS { longest.label }

INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {longest.label.pass}

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

I'm using FUNCTION{article} for all my references.

I first used format.vol.num.pages but then I realized the features only pop up in the output when they're all together present in the Bibtex input.

So I separated them and the output came close to my needs, but still not sufficient, because I have this:

P. Lopes, M. A. Silva, A. Pons, T. Tominaga, V. Lavigne, C. Saucier, P. Darriet, P. L.
Teissedre e D. Dubourdieu. 2009. Impact of oxygen dissolved at bottling and transmitted
through closures on the composition and sensory properties of a Sauvignon blanc wine
during bottle storage. Volume 57. Edizione 21. 10261–10270. ACS Publications. Journal
of agricultural and food chemistry.

In other words, I need to have the following order of the elements within the reference:

1. authors 2. year 3. title 4. journal 5. volume 6. edition 7. pages 8. editor

While now I have:

1. authors 2. year 3. title 4. volume 5. edition 6. pages 7. editor 8. journal

Can somebody help me solving the problem?

I tried to modify the elements order inside FUNCTION{article} but it did not work because I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Welcome. // Sorry, I don't get your specific problem. May be you can add a sentence or two which makes it clearer?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package? It poses a menu-driven series of questions with multiple possible answers (with the default answer marked with an asterisk). When you're done with the questions, you end up with bespoke bst file that achieves your desired formatting objectives. In my experience, it's much better to produce a new bst file in this manner instead of trying to hack an existing bst file, which may have been subjected to various hacks, of dubious qualities, by previous users.

Comment: Fine: Please it add to your question, using the Edit button; delete this comment afterwards. // It takes a while to get used to this place: avoiding chit-chat, 1 question == 1 complete problem, 1 answer == 1 complete solution ... but it works well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using a code I found at https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/439598/filename/myicarus.bst.

The code is

```
% By Young (and Spencer)
% GNP - fixed bugs with missing volume, number, and/or pages
%
% Format journal, volume, number, pages for article types.
%
FUNCTION {format.jour.vol}
{ journal empty$
    { "no journal in " cite$ * warning$
      "" }
% TG: ADD italic font (NE Putzig 2004/07/29)    
    { journal emphasize.space }
%    { journal }
    if$
  number empty$
    { volume empty$
       { "no number and no volume in " cite$ * warning$
         "" * }
% TG: ADD bold font (NE Putzig 2004/07/29)     
       { "~{\bf " * Volume * "}" * }
%       { "~" * Volume * "" * }
      if$
    }
    { volume empty$
      {"no volume for " cite$ * warning$
       "~(" * number * ")" * }
      { "~" *
% TG: ADD italic font (NE Putzig 2004/07/29)        
         volume emphasize.space
%         volume 
% added space (NE Putzig 2004/07/29)        "(" * number * ")" * * }
        " (" * number * ")" * * }
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    {"page numbers missing in " cite$ * warning$
     "" * } % gnp - place a null string on the stack for output
    { duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ format.pages }
      { ", " *  pages n.dashify * } % gnp - removed pp. for articles
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```